# unity3d Establecer recuadro/campo de vision de camera

Tags: unity3d

Me estoy volviendo loco con una cosa que en teoria debe de ser simple.

Estoy creado un juego en 3d y quiero establecer el campo de visión de una camera en Unity3d. quiero hacer que sea un recuadro en el que yo elija las medidas y la camara se ajuste a ese tamaño de campo de vision.

Alguien sabe como hacer eso...gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes darme alguna imagen de referencia de lo que quieres?

1. Si quieres cambiar la proporcion de la camara una opcion es usar 2 camaras y que una apunte a un render texture. y cambiar la proporción de la camara que apunta al meshrender.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Si quieres cambiar la cantidad de objetos en pantalla puedes aumentar o disminuir al campo de vision hasta 180gradis vista de pez, solo para camaras 3d.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Si solo quieres bloquear lo que se puedes agregar un canvas con una o varias imagenes que bloquen lo que se ve.
4. Tambien existe un postpocesameinto que agrega un circulo al rededor.

Toma captures como ejemplo para ayudarte mejor